# Pawn structure search in Scid on the Go

Tags: android

In scid on the go on android, latest version, I would like to search for a given pawn structure in the current database.

In "search" then "search current board" the closest to "search a pawn structure" would be "same material, all pawns on same squares", but it will obviously not provide what I am looking for. Plus, the "search current board" would concern ... the current board, while I would rather prefer to search directly the database. For this we have the "search" then "search header" menu, but it doesn't contain searching for a given pawn structure.

Am I missing something or is this not possible in Scid on the go on android ?

(I am not putting the scid tag as this is not a question related to scid (where searching for a pawn structure is by the way possible) but to the android app scid on the go.)

Comment: @RewanDemontay Are you kidding me ? I explicity write in my question that I am not tagging my question with "scid" as it concerns "scid on the go", and you edit my question by adding a scid tag ?! Please read question before editing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a not missing anything and it is indeed not possible, confirmed by the app programmer, which pointed to me the repository of its app :

https://github.com/gkalab/scidonthego

and saying that he won't provide any support/modifications except bug correction for scid on the go in the future. He is by the way happy to receive pull requests from other contributors, I will give it a try if I can spare time.